# Why is my jade code producing undesired text nodes?

Tags: pug

I am setting variables inside conditional blocks in Jade.
I have a number of objects that have zero, one, or two of two different types of ratings.
Each object gets two `<span>` tags. The span tags are left blank if the rating doesn't exist. Otherwise I insert the appropriate rating into my span tag. I need the variables for future use further down the DOM.

You can experiment with the following Jade code here:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/a5rru5vj

**EDIT:** trivial solution below, leaving this up in case it helps others :D

```
//Jade
- var demo = [{rating1:'2.5'}, {rating2:3.333333}]
each obj in demo
  if(obj.rating1 !== undefined)
    - var r1 = obj.rating1 || ""
    = r1 
  else
    - var r1 = ""
    = r1
  if(obj.rating2 !== undefined)
    - var r2 = String(obj.rating2).slice(0,3) 
    = r2
  else
    - var r2 = ""
    = r2
  div.objIndex(data-obj=JSON.stringify(obj))
    span.myRating= r1
    span.googleRating= r2
```

---

```
// output html (with whitespace cleaned up)
// Note that Jade is writing the variables into the output, why, and how to avoid this?
<body>
  2.5
  <div data-obj="{&quot;rating1&quot;:&quot;2.5&quot;}" class="objIndex">
    <span class="myRating">
      2.5
    </span>
    <span class="googleRating">
    </span>
  </div>
    3.3
    <div data-obj="{&quot;rating2&quot;:3.333333}" class="objIndex">
      <span class="myRating">
      </span>
      <span class="googleRating">
        3.3
      </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `= r1` and `= r2` lines are the culprits. I added those recently trying to fix something else which is not reproduced in the sample code above.